Is it a good decision to use mobilenetv2 for classification of waste between recycle and non recycle
I am trying to find a solution for my business problem of classifying recyclable and non-recyclable materials for waste management. I’m a master’s student and still learning. I started with YOLOv8, but after reading a few articles, I decided to use MobileNetV2 with transfer learning. Is this a good choice? If not, what is the best way to solve this problem? Any help would be much appreciated.
